# Dump WebRequest transmissions for debugging purposes?

Tags: .net

My application is performing numerous `HttpWebRequest`s, and some of them fail occasionally. I would like to dump the bytes leaving my PC whenever I perform a request as well as the bytes arriving as a response.

Is it possible to do this from within my code easily?

I'd only like to use something like Wireshark as a last resort if no other method is available, as I'd like such dumping to be available on the clients' machines without having to install WinPcap and stuff.

Comment: It's amazing how hard such simple things are when you're using Windows.  Over-engineered WebRequest class has no way of seeing the request body??? Even Wireshark is impossible on localhost because Windows has no loopback interface.

Comment: @JoeKoberg haters gonna hate... but so that you don't look quite that lame, [here's an _actual_ crapness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561545) in Windows itself (as opposed to some random API) that you can use to show why Windows is so crap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Fidller2 -- yeah it is installing something, but it's not anywhere near as involved as wireshark and it will give you much more useful information. Including being able to dump the streams into re-playable series.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question but was very helpful nevertheless. For the record, I found no way of doing exactly what the question asks.

Answer (score 0):

There is Microsoft's [NetMon](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=f4db40af-1e08-4a21-a26b-ec2f4dc4190d&displaylang=en) or as you said a WinPCap based product like Wireshark.  Just like Wireshark, it can be overkill for just HTTP.

As the other post said, there is [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a lot easy to use for debugging HTTP.  Also it is useful in debugging HTTPS where NetMon/Wireshark is of no use...

Answer (score 0):

What I'm doing now is wrapping `HttpWebRequest` into a class which just dumps all the response headers and body into a specified file. Same for the request, though it's a bit clumsy with POST requests.

The worst thing about this is that I have to change all code that uses HttpWebRequest to use this new wrapper class, but it's not too bad.

Comment: Now that it's been a couple of months, the wrapping solution made a bunch of other things easier too, so overall I think this was the right decision for my particular use case.

Comment: throw us a bone and at least mention what method needs to be overridden to get the output???

Comment: @JoeKoberg The wrapper does not derive from `HttpWebRequest`, so nothing to override. It just logs whatever information I can pull out of the request/response.