# Suppress error window on catastrophic powershell process failure

Tags: powershell

I am automating some report generation with Powershell. It is an unpleasant business, collaging together PDFs with Excel interop and third-party DLLs. Due to all the sketchy things I'm trying to marshall together, sometimes my powershell process dies completely. To mitigate this, I'm running it in a supervisor script something like this:

```
while($moreToDo) {

    try {
        powershell -NonInteractive -NoProfile ./generate-report.ps1
    }
    catch {
        # clean up
        Write-Host "Failed. Trying again..."
    }
}
```

However, when the `powershell` process dies, I get a 'windows powershell has stopped working' dialog:

[image]

This dialog blocks the supervisor script from continuing, which makes my supervisor script pretty pointless.

Is there a way to invoke powershell so that if it fails catastrophically , it doesn't pop up this message and instead just *dies*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561545/how-to-terminate-a-program-when-it-crashes-which-should-just-fail-a-unit-test

Comment: Are you using a GUI of some sort (Windows Forms or WPF) ?

Comment: @sodawillow My script is just a plain old powershell script. But it's calling out to Excel interop, which means it's firing up GUI Excel processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That dialog is put up by the [Windows Error Reporting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513613(v=vs.85).aspx) system.  It's the OS responding to the powershell.exe process crashing.

It is possible to disable WER or to configure WER to ignore powershell.exe.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3637710.  That's a very dangerous road to travel, however.

A **much better idea** is to modify your script to not crash PowerShell.  If you post a question with code, we may be able to help you figure out what is causing the crash and how to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks, good to know about WER. I'm well aware that it is a much better idea to fix my script. However, it's a bodged-together one-off yak-shaving rush-job full of workarounds and hacks. I don't think it's worth trying to chase down the infrequent and quasi-random failures: I will just deal with it dying occasionally and kill the WER messages when I need to.