# How to disable application popup after a crash and enable the crash dumps

Tags: registry, crash-reports, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

We have an IIS process running inside a container (w3wp.exe) and we used to have the crash dumps generated on all crashes. But, something changed and we're not seeing the dumps anymore. When I investigated more I noticed that there is an Application Popup evnt (event ID 26) in the System logs that this process crashed. I looked for ways to disable and bypass this popup and generate the dumps. I found bunch of stack overflow questions [How do I disable the 'Debug / Close Application' dialog on Windows Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396369/how-do-i-disable-the-debug-close-application-dialog-on-windows-vista) and [How to terminate a program when it crashes? (which should just fail a unit test instead of getting stuck forever)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561545/how-to-terminate-a-program-when-it-crashes-which-should-just-fail-a-unit-test/3637710#3637710)

I've tried to set these reg keys but no luck.
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting]
    "DontShowUI"=dword:00000001
    "Disabled"=dword:00

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting]
"DontShowUI"=dword:00000001
"Disabled"=dword:00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting]
"Disabled"=dword:00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting]
"Disabled"=dword:00

//Registry Key Configuration for Up-Level Clients
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting]
"Disabled"=dword:00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting]
"Disabled"=dword:00
```

Also, the w3wp.exe process runs under NT Authority\System user which is the localsystemaccount and I've found out that it reads the HKEY_USERS.Default registry hive. So I modified these keys under that as well but still no luck.

My OS is win10. Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I found HKLM keys to disable it (I needed it disabled for all users).  This worked for me:

reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting"
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting" /V DontShowUI /t reg_dword /d "1"

I found the key here:
https://www.raymond.cc/blog/disable-program-has-stopped-working-error-dialog-in-windows-server-2008/